# VBA - assinging data to line chart via VBA gets 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic line chart in Excel with VBA. My relevant data gets updated and my chart should grab this new data (range) automatically. Hence I created dynamic name ranges that should be assigned to my chart with a macro.

To assign the data for the x-axis (named *UL1_months* below) **works**, to assign data for the y-axis (values; *UL1_histdata*) doesn't and throws me a runtime error 1004.

I try to change the values of my chart like that:

```
variable = "SampleSheet" 
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & variable & "'!UL1_months" 
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & variable &"'!UL1_histdata"
```

where named dynamic ranged are defined as following

> 'SampleSheet'!UL1_histdata
>   =OFFSET('SampleSheet'!$B$10,,,COUNTIF('SampleSheet'!$B$10:$B$10000,"<>"))
>
> 'SampleSheet'!UL1_months
>   =OFFSET('SampleSheet'!$A$10,,,COUNTIF('SampleSheet'!$A$10:$A$10000,"<>"))

Short note: assigning my month range to x values work fine without errors:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & ID & "'!UL1_months"
```

so I thought that the issues occurs from the UL1_histdata name range, but I cannot find the reason (Despite that my range B10:B10000 is blank at the beginning (gets values after refresh), where my range for months A10:A1000 at least has a "start" value in A10. Initially I was thinking that this caused the error, but putting a vlue in B10 just to avoid the cell being empty doesn't help.)

Happy to hear from you.

TW

Comment: As a test, set `.Values` to equal the same things as `.XValues`.  If this works it will let you know there's something wrong with `UL1_histdata`.  If it doesn't then we'll know there's something else going on.

Comment: Don't know if this would cause your error but do they have the same number of values?

Comment: @SJR, just tested it.  It won't throw an error if the counts don't match.

Comment: Can you post your full code, as in [mcve] ? @DavidN - ok, thanks.

Comment: I think that the `COUNTIF` may be giving you a different result. If you are OFFSET with ifs based on `<>` in separate columns

Comment: I never do COUNT or COUNTA or COUNTIF on multiple columns. I do it on the X values, then simply offset that to get each successive set of Y values. That way, there's only one chance to get it wrong. For example, if the whole Y values range is blank, you'll be defining a zero-cell range, and it will crash.